# trailing comma in define macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I came across this code.

```
#define LIST_ENTRY(_type)\
_type##_auth_detach,
static int (*func[])(int x) = 
{
    LIST_ENTRY(foo)
    0
};
```

Is this trailing comma syntactically valid in C?

Comment: Valid depending on how `LIST_ENTRY()` is used (Can only be in places where a comma is allowed), but poor style.

Comment: Look at where the macro is used for hints.

Comment: Anything in a macro definition is syntactically valid, at least until the macro is used, but this one would fail to compile.

Comment: You need to provide some context. Where is this used? Part of array initialization? Enum? Is it a "X macro" list?

Comment: Is there a `_` missing from the start of the replacement text?

Comment: Run the code through the preprocessor to see its output and how the macro was expanded.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understood it.

Comment: @bipll: Re “Anything in a macro definition is syntactically valid”: Almost. `#define foo{}` and `#define foo __VA_ARGS__` violate constraints in C 2018 6.10.3 paragraphs 3 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it appears to simply be an array initializer list where the macro expands the list to:

```
{
    foo_auth_detach,
    0
};
```

where the comma is necessary to make the array initializer syntax valid. In this specific case, it didn't make much sense - `LIST_ENTRY(foo),` had been much clearer.

But there are other very similar cases where you wish to avoid code repetition by using "X-macros" to centralize all data to one place, and have something like this:

```
#define LIST \
  X(foo)     \
  X(bar)     \

...

static int (*func[])(int x) = 
{
  #define X(_type) _type##_auth_detach,
    LIST
  #undef X
    0
};
```

which expands to

```
{
    foo_auth_detach,
    bar_auth_detach,
    0
};
```

In this "X macro" case, the `,` is not only necessary to for the final `0` argument, but for every argument provided in the list.

Note that array initializer lists may end with a trailing `,` so `0,` would have been valid. This is also true for `enum` lists, since C99. Macro tricks like the ones above is one reason why.